# Upload Image VarBinary(max) using AngularJS and WebService (.asmx)

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, web-services, asmx

I am still new in AngularJS and I want to create a form that allow me to upload an image and save it to a database and view it on a html page.

.asmx File

```
public void AddCard(int id, string cName, string cCoName, string cTpNmbr, string cEmail, string cAddress, string cStatus,string cScan)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
           byte[] cScan = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblCards(Id, Name, CoName, TpNmbr, Email, Address, Status, Scan) values('"+id+"','"+cName+"', '"+cCoName+"','" +cTpNmbr+"', '"+cEmail+"', '"+cAddress+"', '"+cStatus+"',@cScan)", con);
           SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cScan", cScan);
            param.DbType = DbType.Binary;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

.html File

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> ADD CARD / EDIT CARD </legend>
        <p> ID : <input type="text" ng-model="cards.id" /></p>
        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="cards.cName" /></p>
        <p>Co. Name :<input type="text" ng-model="cards.cCoName" /></p>
        <p>Tp. Number : <input type="text" ng-model="cards.cTpNmbr" /></p>
        <p>Email : <input type="text" ng-model="cards.cEmail" /></p>
        <p>Address : <textarea ng-model="cards.cAddress"></textarea></p>
        <p>Status : <input type="text" ng-model="cards.cStatus" /></p>
        <p>Card Scan : <input type="file" ng-model="cards.cScan" /></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addCard(cards)"> Add Card </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editCards(cards)"> Edit Card </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary"> Reset Form </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

AngularJS File

```
$scope.addCard = function (card) {
    var id = card.id
    var cName = card.cName;
    var cCoName = card.cCoName;
    var cTpNmbr = card.cTpNmbr;
    var cEmail = card.cEmail;
    var cStatus = card.cStatus;
    var cAddress = card.cAddress;
    var cCount = card.cCount;
    var cScan = card.cScan;
    cCount = 0;
    $http({
        url: 'CardServices.asmx/AddCard',
        params: {
            id: id,
            cName: cName,
            cCoName: cCoName,
            cTpNmbr: cTpNmbr,
            cEmail: cEmail,
            cStatus: cStatus,
            cAddress: cAddress,
            cScan:cScan
        },
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        GetAllCards();
        alert("Card Added to Database!");

    });
    }
```

I looked up online and I've tried to use the code but it seems like it is 
 not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "...i try to use the code but it seems like it is working."  What's the question, then?  Are you getting an error? Some sort of unexpected result?  It's not clear where to even begin here.

Comment: also, is `cScan` your image? because you declared it as a `string`....

Comment: cScan suppose to be my image.. if string is wrong, then what type should i declare as?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).